# Is this usage of "lest" possible?

Tags: grammar

The only danger is, lest it should be Too strong a remedy ...[Source](https://archive.org/stream/britishpoetsincl03chis/britishpoetsincl03chis_djvu.txt)

Can this "lest" be used in this way?

Like this...

My apprehension is lest my advice should kill her motivation.

Comment: Searching Google books for "is lest it" reveals a multitude of instances where "lest" is used in exactly this way. 

However, most of them are from the 19th century, and my feeling is that this usage is now archaic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as such, really. The word "lest" can be loosely read as "if" or "in case".

Let's have a look at a larger excerpt of your source text, reformatted more prosaically:

> *The only danger is, **lest it should be too strong a remedy**; **lest,** in removing cold, **it should beget too violent a heat**; and into madness turn the lethargy.*

As you can see, the two clauses I highlighted above indicate possible reasons that taking the action ("removing cold") could result in the stated outcome ("into madness turn the lethargy").

Thus, your sentence could be better expressed as

> My apprehension is {**great/well-founded/justified/etc.,**} lest my advice <del>should</del> kill her motivation.

The addition of an adjective and a comma fixes it right up. *(I can't explain why I struck out the "should", but my native-English-speaker "Spidey-sense" tells me to get rid of it. I leave it as an exercise to the resident English majors to rationalize it. :-)*

Comment: Because you're American. ‘Lest’ requires the subjunctive mood, and substituting ‘should + infinitive’ for the subjunctive is a very BrE trait.